# Installing gstreamer 1.0 on windows for python 2.7.

Tags: python, python-2.7, gstreamer, pygst

I've been trying to install gstreamer 1.0 on windows to use as a python 2.7 module. I installed the sdk from here http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+on+Windows which allows me to `import pygst`, but it only allows me to use gstreamer 0.1 (If I try `pygst.require('1.0')` I get a pygst.RequiredVersionError only version '0.10' is available).

I looked all over for a gstreamer 1.0 version of the sdk with no luck, so I'm hoping I can maybe alter the 0.1 sdk for my needs.

I've downloaded gstreamer 1.0 from here http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/1.5.2/ but I'm not actually sure what to do with it after I fix the RequiredVersionError/obtain the proper sdk. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

With Python 3.4.3 works.

1. Download from:
   http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/?source=navbar
2. Install in Windows `pygi-aio-3.14.0_rev22-setup.exe`
3. In the program .py:

   ```
   import gi

   gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')

   from gi.repository import Gst

   pipeline = Gst.Pipeline.new("player")

   src = Gst.ElementFactory.make("audiotestsrc", "src")

   sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("autoaudiosink", "output")

   pipeline.add(src)

   pipeline.add(sink)

   src.link(sink)

   pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
   ```

And enjoy more ..

Comment: But this is not for Python 2.7