# How can I install gstreamer 1.0 library for python 3.5+ on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.5, python-3.6

I want to install the gstreamer 1.0 library on Windows for either Python 3.5 or 3.6. Either will work.

I tried the answer to the question [Installing gstreamer 1.0 on windows for python 2.7.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31149041/installing-gstreamer-1-0-on-windows-for-python-2-7#33732871), but the library listed there only supports up to Python 3.4. I ran the installer and it didn't recognize my Python 3.5/3.6 installations.

I've done some searching and it looks like they haven't officially released a Python 3.5+ version for Windows. Is there a third-party binary or something that would enable this to work?